# Get Multi Columns Count in Single Query

Tags: mysql, sql, vertica

I am working on a application where I need to write a query on a table, which will return multiple columns count in a single query.

After research I was able to develop a query for a single sourceId, but what will happen if i want result for multiple sourceIds.

```
select '3'as sourceId,
   (select count(*) from event where sourceId = 3 and plateCategoryId = 3) as TotalNewCount,
   (select count(*) from event where sourceId = 3 and plateCategoryId = 4) as TotalOldCount;
```

I need to get TotalNewCount and TotalOldCount for several source Ids, for example (3,4,5,6)

Can anyone help, how can I revise my query to return a result set of three columns including data of all sources in list (3,4,5,6)

Thanks

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Vertica?  Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: I am using both. 
We are testing scalability at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all source ids at once:

```
select source_id
       sum(case when plateCategoryId = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalNewCount,
       sum(case when plateCategoryId = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalOldCount
from event
group by source_id;
```

Use a `where` (before the `group by`) if you want to limit the source ids.

Note:  The above works in both Vertica and MySQL, and being standard SQL should work in any database.