# Get Multi Columns Count in Single Query for different Date Ranges

Tags: mysql, sql

Following to my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46888967/get-multi-columns-count-in-single-query) few days ago, we were able to get desired results.
Now we have new requirement to draw event counts on graph, we need to specify date ranges and results will be limited within date ranges (epoch). I was able to do it with two separate queries as below but it does not seem good option.

**Question**

Is there any other way to combine these two queries in single query and get result of these two queries in different result sets?

```
select source_id
       sum(case when plateCategoryId = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalNewCount,
       sum(case when plateCategoryId = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalOldCount
from event where eventTime >= 1451606400 and eventTime <= 1454284800 
group by source_id;

select source_id
       sum(case when plateCategoryId = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalNewCount,
       sum(case when plateCategoryId = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalOldCount
from event where eventTime >= 1456790400 and eventTime <= 1459468800
group by source_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select source_id
       sum(case when plateCategoryId = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalNewCount,
       sum(case when plateCategoryId = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalOldCount
from event 
where (eventTime >= 1451606400 and eventTime <= 1454284800) OR
      (eventTime >= 1456790400 and eventTime <= 1459468800) 
group by source_id;
```

Comment: We need different counts for both queries, as count should be group by defined date range.

Comment: Add the time range to the `case` expressions. `sum(case when patecategoryId = 3 AND eventTime BETWEEN 1451606400 AND 1454284800 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`